# Insertar imagen en un input tomando foto desde la cámara del pc y enviar a controlador laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, canvas

hola necesito ayuda con un proyecto que estoy realizando, tengo un input file en un formulario que deseo enviar a mi servidor php con laravel, asi mismo tengo un boton que abre la camara de la laptop y la captura en un canvas... quiero hacer que, esa imagen se procese y se envie en el input fyle a mi servidor.. les pongo mi codigo que he probado pero no funciona (javascript):

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 100, 0, 480, video.videoHeight, 0, 0, 120, 160);
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
previa.setAttribute('src', data);
$("#foto").val(data);  -->>> esta es la linea  donde intento setear el input
```

Intente asi y tambien con javascript puro en vez de val

```
document.getElementById('foto').setAttribute('value', data);
```

les muestro el codigo html que tengo

```
<video id="video" width="auto" height="auto" autoplay class="img-responsive"></video>
<a id="startbutton" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: -20%">Tomar foto</a>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: none" width="122"></canvas>
<input id="foto" name="foto" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

la verdad no se que esta mal por que al querer guardar y al enviar este dato con la imagen, me sale que el campo foto no debe ser vacio, por que asi lo tengo validado en el servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí hacerlo y queria responder a mi pregunta: lo que hice fue poner un input en el formulario que se iba a enviar (esto de lado del cliente):

```
<input id='fotocamara' name="fotocamara" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none" />
```

para hacer la captura utilicé javascript, convirtiendo la imagen a formato url, y eso lo insertaba en el input de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById("startbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 100, 0, 480, video.videoHeight, 0, 0, 120, 160); 
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.getElementById('fotocamara').setAttribute('value', data);  });
```

y de lado del servidor, en mi controlador lo que hago es leer ese input y convertirlo a base64:

```
 $img = $request->fotocamara;
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $image = base64_decode($img);

 $extension="png";
 $filename='fotocamara'.date('Y-m-d').'.'.$extension;
 //guardamos archivo 
 Image::make($image)->resize(144,144)->save(public_path("storage\\personas\\".$filename));
```